# if (mysql_num_rows(($result1) && $result) == 0) {

Tags: php

This is probably like the most stupid question, but I can't figure it out, and I don't know why, but it's giving me an error saying that it was given a boolean. Here is my code.

```
if (mysql_num_rows(($result1) && $result) == 0) {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>No such user: <b>$u_name</b></div>";
    exit();
}
```

EDIT:

I feel like the error is around in here somewhere, like is there a misplaced bracket or something like that:

```
if (mysql_num_rows(($result1) && $result) == 0)
```

Comment: Don't you think you need to provide us with just a little bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result1) == 0 && $result)
```

`mysql_num_rows()` expects the result of `mysql_query()`, see https://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows. You were trying to provide it a boolean:

```
mysql_num_rows($result1 && $result) == 0)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Does this check if $result1 is = 0 and then check if $result is = 0?

Comment: @Schnebz okay glad to hear it, keep in mind this is completely untested :)